# find an ONB of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that a given rotation has the following matrice

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, change-of-basis

I am stuck on the following linear algebra problem :

Consider $\mathbb{R}^3$ and its canonical basis $\{ i,j,k \}$ and let $r$ denote the 90° angle rotation around the axis given by the vector $u := i+j$. I am asked to find an orthonormal basis (ONB) $\{ a,b,c \}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the matrix of $r$ with respect to the basis $\{ a,b,c \}$ has the following form :

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}

Isn't this the matrix of the 90° angle rotation around the x-axis ? Anyway I thought that I should tried to put the vector $u$ in the place of the x-axis so I tried the following :

\begin{align}
    a &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           1 \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

a unit vector colinear with the axis of rotation. From $a$ I figured out that the tangent plan to $a$ through 0 is given by :
$$ P: x+y=0. $$

I noticed that

\begin{align}
    b &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}
           -1 \\
           1 \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

lies in $P$ and is unitary. Now I find a third unit vector by computing the vector product of $a$ and $$ and diving the result by its norm :

\begin{align}
    a \times b &= \begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           0 \\
           1
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

Is it correct to assume that the matrix of $r$ with respect to the basis $\{ a,b,c \}$ is

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}

?

Thanks for your help.